# Debian package containing base64.h

Tags: package, base64, debian

I am building a project on Debian and I am getting an error base64.h not found.

Is there a package I am needing to install for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search at http://packages.debian.org, as eg [this search shows](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=base64.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=any).

Comment: apt-get install heimdal-dev generates the error E: Unable to locate package heimdal-dev what line do I have to add to my sources.list?

Comment: I installed apt-get install libnss3-dev and still I get the error for bse64.h I installed heimdal-dev and it works. Now I need a package with vsockets.h???? packages.debian.org does not find it

Comment: I know that is a new question, sorry

Comment: I did apply the learnings in this thread to no avail though. thank you